# Examples of the physical significance and importance of matrix diagonalization and eigenvalues for first year undergraduates?

Tags: operators, education, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

To a student of physics, who is only exposed to the techniques of mathematical physics and read classical mechanics at the undergraduate level, but not quantum mechanics yet, how can we explain the importance and significance of matrix diagonalization/similarity transformation, eigenvalues, etc.? How can I introduce the idea of matrix diagonalization in a natural way, in some physical context, not as an abstract mathematical procedure?

Comment: _"Eigenvalues are not special to QM."_ True. Thanks, your example an eigenvalue problem in terms of differential equations. How about matrices? Inertia tensor? Do you know of a reference where the idea of matrix diagonalization is motivated using a physical context rather than as an abstract mathematical procedure?

Comment: I think the mathematical motivation for diagonalizing the inertia tensor is rather convincing on its own. Surely, if you've done enough classical mechanics problems, you know the value of picking the right coordinate system. (Although this may be emphasized more in engineering than physics.) But this is often difficult in practice, whereas you can just set up the inertia tensor, diagonalize it, and get the principal axes of rotation.

Comment: I have down voted / voted to close this question because it is subjective, and there could end up being multiple "correct" answers.

Comment: What is wrong with multiple correct answers? I am not asking what is the BEST way to understand this and so my question is not subjective. I am okay with more than one answer as long as they are correct.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so one should ask questions that have an objective answer. Additionally this is subjective, as users could agree or disagree on whether or not you should use a given approach to teach the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a physics application per se, but I remember that as a first year undergrad I was convinced in the usefulness of matrix diagonalization by the application to obtain a closed expression for the Fibonacci sequence, as explained for example here: https://austinrochford.com/posts/2014-04-23-diagonalization-fibonacci.html
For me, it shows that I can use eigenvectors to easily obtain a non-trivial result. When this is shown one can be convinced that it might be useful in more physically-motivated cases as well.

Later note: Such transfer matrix methods have also widespread uses in physics. As an example, you can consider a particle moving on a 1D lattice with $N$ sites, where for each lattice point it could be in sublattice A or B (think of a ladder-like lattice). We assign probabilities for the particle to move from A/B in site $n$ to A/B in site $n+1$ by the matrix
$$P=\pmatrix{p_{AA} & p_{AB}\\ p_{BA} & p_{BB}}$$
What is then the probability for a particle starting at site A at $n=1$ to reach site B at $n=N$? It is simply
$(P^n)_{AB}$, which can easily be found by diagonalizing $P$.